# Import "Flask" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.10, issue-tracking

Just started making a website using flask on python3.10, and having such an issue.[image: Python Code].[image: HTML Code]

I tried to install `venv`; updating vscode and reinstalling `Flask`.

Eventually, it installed, which I wasn't expecting to...
But it didn't really fixed my problem.
Stuck on this for couple of hours just surfing the web for the answer but nothing.

Comment: How are you activating your venv in VSCode?

Comment: Are you able to successfully run the script? If so and your concern is pylance error reporting, it's probably because you haven't selected the correct interpreter in vscode